# 'IronSource/IronSource.h' file not found error Unity XCode in iOSBridge.h file

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine

I should mention that I'm not experienced in XCode debugging, that being said, I have been using XCode to build my unity project to TestFlight for some time now and I haven't experienced this until now.

[image: error]

What I'm confused about is that all of this is straight exported from Unity so surely it should just work? If anyone has any experience with this error, I would much appreciate some insight, thank you for any contribution!

Comment: Hi, i assume you are having this after adding new Unity Levelplay sdk right? i'm having same issue once i use the new sdk.

Comment: @BrutalJazzy Hi, mine turned out to be me opening the wrong xcode file from the builds folder. Sorry I can't help more than that

Answer (score 2):

In my case I simply hadn't realised that after adding ironsource sdk my Unity build has to create a xcworkspace that contains my proj and the pods proj.

Open the workspace, dont open the xcproj on its own file or else you get this error.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by:

1. manually downloading the corresponding [iOS SDK](https://github.com/ironsource-mobile/iOS-sdk)
2. unzipping it
3. adding the **IronSource.framework** directory in *Assets/IronSource/Plugins/iOS*.